# The system cannot find the path specified after reinstalling RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need some help with something that is driving me crazy. After reinstalling RoR using RailsInstaller on Windows, I get a 'The system cannot find the path specified' error on the Windows command line. If I use Git Bash, however, the error is not shown and Rails works.

The path variable seems to be set correctly . Ruby2.2.0\bin, Git\cmd are added to the path.

PATH VAR AFTER ADDING RAILS.BAT, FOLLOWING RAILSUSER SUGGESTION

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\rails.bat;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Sonia\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\AMI\DuOS\
```

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: can you show the the path file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rails.bat file contained a wrong path.    `@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe"` Maybe it is one of the developers that worked on this.

A temporary fix is to change the rails.bat file as the below code:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

Comment: I also had to update the bundle.bat file in the same directory to make the bundle commands work (i.e. `bundle install`)

Answer (score 7):

step 1: open the rails.bat file(D:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\rails.bat)

step 2: Find the lines as look like this (for me line No 3 and 7)
**@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe"**

step 3:Just replace with **@"%~dp0ruby.exe"** and save

After changing, Your file look like this

```
 @ECHO OFF
 IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
 @"%~dp0ruby.exe"
 "C:/Users/emachnic/GitRepos/railsinstaller-windows/stage/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
 GOTO :EOF
 :WinNT
 @"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

step 4: Repeat the same in **bundle.bat** file

step 5:Run the command **rails -v** in command prompt

Hope it Works..

Answer (score 1):

The rails.bat file (for me located in C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin) has a hard-coded path that is not accurate. Edit that file and add your path.